# Follow Facebook User With Facebook API (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, facebook, api

I want to create a button which onClick will follow specified user on Facebook with their API in JavaScript but, I came across nothing so I have no clue - is it even possible?

Answer (score 0):

This facebook [documentation page](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/follow-button) includes instructions concerning how to create a follow button using the facebook API:

> Include the JavaScript SDK on your page once, ideally right after the opening  tag.
>
> ```
> <div id="fb-root"></div>
> <script>(function(d, s, id) {
>   var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
>   if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
>   js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
>   js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_GB/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.3&appId=999677273376981";
>   fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
> }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
> ```
>
> Place the code for your plugin wherever you want the plugin to appear on your page.
>
> `<div class="fb-follow" data-href="https://www.facebook.com/zuck" data-colorscheme="light" data-layout="standard" data-show-faces="true"></div>`

To change the user pointed to change the `data-href` attribute of the follow button:

```
<div class="fb-follow" data-href="https://www.facebook.com/{the person you want to follow}" data-colorscheme="light" data-layout="standard" data-show-faces="true"></div>
```